# Recv() skips bytes

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using recv on a basic TCP connection. This is the []byte which I'm reading: [ 0 4 9 0 ]

Here are the recv calls and at the end the code in context

```
recv(fd_serv, &len, sizeof (len), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
len = ntohs(len);
recv(fd_serv, &tool_id, sizeof (tool_id), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
recv(fd_serv, rdbuf, len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

When debugging in gdb I can see that

```
len = 4
tool_id = 9
rdbuf = [ 0 4 9 0 ] / [ 0 4 \t 0 ]
```

How is that possible? It looks like recv takes the first two bytes for len and the next byte for tool_id (like the length / size), while taking all bytes for rdbuf. I'd expect it to be consistent. I thought this might be a feature for partial byte reading, but apparently I'm wrong.

If I remove

```
recv(fd_serv, &tool_id, sizeof (tool_id), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

from the code and check rdbuf in gdb the first 2 byte change after executing

```
recv(fd_serv, rdbuf, len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

it becomes

```
[ 9 0 9 0 ] / [ \t 0 \t 0 ]
```

When I uncomment it again, the rdbuf is normal again. At first I thought the leftover bytes which weren't read are copied over. I set rdbuf[3] to 5 and thought it might replace 0 then, but it didn't. As of now I'm clueless on what is happening here and why it is inconsistent here.

I'm using Arch Linux x86_64 gdb 7.12.1, gcc 6.3.1 and this to build :

```
gcc -g -DDEBUG *.c -o client.dbg -lcrypto
```

Context

```
while(TRUE) { 
    if (fd_serv != -1 && FD_ISSET(fd_serv, &fdsetrd)) {
        int n;
        uint16_t len;
        uint8_t tool_id;
        char rdbuf[1024];

        errno = 0;
        n = recv(fd_serv, &len, sizeof (len), MSG_NOSIGNAL | MSG_PEEK);
        if (n == -1) {
            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
                n = 0; 
        }

        if (n == 0) {
            close_connection();
            continue;
        }

        if (len == 0) {
            recv(fd_serv, &len, sizeof (len), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
            continue;
        }
        len = ntohs(len);
        if (len > sizeof (rdbuf)) {
            close(fd_serv);
            fd_serv = -1;
        }

        errno = 0;
        n = recv(fd_serv, rdbuf, len, MSG_NOSIGNAL | MSG_PEEK);
        if (n == -1) {
            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
                n = 0;
        }

        if (n == 0) {
            close_connection();
            continue;
        }

        recv(fd_serv, &len, sizeof (len), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        len = ntohs(len);
        recv(fd_serv, &tool_id, sizeof (tool_id), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        recv(fd_serv, rdbuf, len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

        printf("%d\n", tool_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to always check the return value from `recv()`. It tells you not only about errors but it tells you how many bytes have actually been returned by the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the return value of recv helps in this case (as a response to Michael Burrs comment). I came to the conclusion that the last recv call doesn't read all bytes, but only the left over ones. Which are either 1 or 2 in this case. The bytes are then placed at the beginning, while the old values are not overwritten. I think this combination confused me.